# ng-repeat parse array into string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to parse in ng-repeat a array value into a string? I'll explain what I mean.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="(key,property) in obj.properties">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td>{{property}}</td>
 </tr>
```

This {{property}} is an array e.g [ 7 , 8 ], but I would like to show "Jully - August". Is it possible through a filter? Or I need to parse it in the controller.

Comment: Hey guys! thanks a lot =) I ended up solving it ... I hope this helps others with the same question. I'll select an answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter convert number to name of month:-

```
<td>{{property|monthName}}</td>

   app.filter('monthName', [function() {
    return function (monthNumber) { 
      //1 = January
        var monthNames = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
            'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];
         var nameList="";
         for(var i=0;i<monthNumber.length;i++){
           if(i==monthNumber.length-1){
         nameList+=monthNames[monthNumber[i] - 1];
           }else{
             nameList+=monthNames[monthNumber[i] - 1]+"-";
           }
         }
         return nameList;
    }
}]);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/txViwn4SHnOWzKaqP8JE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as well

```
<td>{{property|showMonthName}}</td>

app.filter('showMonthName', function() {
    return function (months) {
    var monthNames = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
        'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];

    months = months.map(function(i){
      return monthNames[i-1];
    }); 

   return months.join(' - ');    
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried this in my own system. I created one filter and applied inside ng-repeat. It works perfectly. You can modify your own filter based on this one.

```
<test-directive keyword = "view.ctrlKeywordinput" ng-repeat="movie in [1,2]" ><div> {{movie | monthfilter}}</div></test-directive>
```

and here is my filter:

```
app.filter("monthfilter", function(){
return function(input){

        switch(input){

        case 1: 
        return "january";
        break;

        case 2:
        return "february";
        break;

        }

    };

});
```